# Linking API on React Native 0.61: openUrl is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make sense of the Docs for the enabling the Linking API in React Native 0.61.5 on iOS.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

The docs say that the library needs to be manually linked by following these steps:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking

But there's no .xcodeproj for Linking, under node_modules/react-native/Library/Linking or node_modules/react-native/Library/LinkingIOS, thus I have not manually linked the Library. Are there alternative instructions on manually linking the library?

When I try to call Linking.openUrl from my App right now, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _reactNative.Linking.openUrl is not a function.
```

also, in my Podfile, I see this line:

```
pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 0.60+, you don't need to do the manual-linking stuff. It uses cocoapods to do the linkings automatically.

Install Cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Then just go to `/ios` folder and do a `pod install`

Comment: Thank you! I had installed the pods as you mentioned, and I was dead set on the issue being the unlinked modules, as that was the only part of the documentation that I could not follow.

After wrapping the call to "openUrl" in a "canOpenUrl", I saw that the issue was specific to the iOS simulator not allowing the Mail App to open. On my physical device, it worked.

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone is as unobservant as I am, it's `openURL`, not `openUrl`. 
Just lost an hour on this.

Comment: Give that man a cookie from me also! I lost half of hour on this.

Comment: This was actually the issue in my case. Thanks!